# AZURE ADB2C - Treat Errors Without Redirect to Application

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I really can't find a clear documentation on adb2c errors and exceptions. The default behavior is to redirect to the application with an error string parameter.

What I'm looking for is to treat errors with my storage content, as the same way I deliver customized visual content for my flows.

Is there a configuration to do so?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to turn off the error handling in the B2C policy (custom policy), eg some technical profiles throw errors with configurable metadata items.

Then put some conditional logic in the user journey to serve a self asserted technical profile with your page customization.

You can see an example in this step [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/invite/policy/SignUpInvitation.xml#L173).

Where an error is thrown due to some unhandled condition, eg bad policy config, that will always return an error to the app.
Buttons such as "Cancel" will always return an error to the app. You can remove or hide these buttons, and put your own button/link, but that will then not be controlled by B2C custom policy.